# Why is this prolog function running indefinitely, how do I fix it?

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

I am trying to create a prolog predicate to solve this zebra problem however It keeps on running indefinitely and does not produce a result, how can I fix this.

Here is the Zebra Problem:

The five biggest DJs in the world are going to play in an electronic music festival, each
one in a specific stage. They are side by side waiting to play. Find out their nationalities,vhobbies and which genre they play.

DJ Properties:

- Shirt colors: black, blue, green, red, white
- Nationalities: American, Canadian, Dutch, French, Scottish
- Music genres: drum and bass, dubstep, EDM, house, trance
- Performance stages: Arcadia, Asgard, Shangri-la, Valhalla, Xibalba
- Ages: 25, 30, 35, 40, 45
- Hobbies: camping, juggling, painting, singing, surfing

Clues

- The Scott is somewhere to the left of the DJ wearing the White shirt.
- At the fourth position is the DJ who is going to play on the Arcadia
  stage.
- The 30-year-old DJ is at the first position.
- The DJ that plays EDM is exactly to the right of the Canadian.
- The one who likes Painting is next to the DJ who plays Dubstep.
- The DJ wearing the Black shirt is somewhere between the Scott and the
  Dubstep player, in that order.
- The French DJ is next to the one wearing the Blue shirt.
- At one of the ends is the DJ that likes Camping.
- The DJ who is going to play on the Asgard stage is wearing the Blue
  shirt.
- The one that likes Painting is somewhere between the DJ wearing Green
  and the DJ wearing Blue, in that order.
- At the fifth position is the DJ who plays Drum and bass.
- In the middle is the DJ who is going to play on the Asgard stage.
- The one who plays Trance is next to the one who plays Dubstep.
- The Canadian is exactly to the left of the DJ who likes Juggling
- The DJ whose hobby is Singing is exactly to the right of the DJ
  wearing the Black shirt.
- The DJ in his Mid-thirties is next to the DJ who is into Juggling.
- The 40-year-old DJ is at the fourth position.
- The 40-year-old DJ is somewhere between the Dutch and the youngest DJ, in that
  order.
- The DJ wearing Blue is somewhere to the left of the DJ who is going to play on the
  Xibalba stage.
- The one who enjoys Surfing is going to play on the Valhalla stage.
- The DJ wearing the Red shirt is somewhere to the right of the French

Here is my code so far:

```
member(X, [X|_]).
member(X, [_|T]) :- member(X, T).

left_of(A, B, L) :- append(_, [A|T], L), member(B, T).

next_to(A, B, L) :- left_of(A, B, L) ; left_of(B, A, L).

solve(DJs) :-
    DJs = [_, _, _, _, _],

    % Clue 1
    member([scott, _, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, white, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    left_of([scott, _, _, _, _, _], [_, white, _, _, _, _], DJs),

    % Clue 2
    DJs = [_, _, _, [_, _, _, arcadia, _, _], _],

    % Clue 3
    DJs = [[_, _, _, _, 30, _], _, _, _, _],

    % Clue 4
    member([canadian, _, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, _, edm, _, _, _], DJs),
    left_of([canadian, _, _, _, _, _], [_, _, edm, _, _, _], DJs),

    % Clue 5
    next_to([_, _, _, _, _, painting], [_, _, dubstep, _, _, _], DJs),

    % Clue 6
    left_of([scott, _, _, _, _, _], [_, black, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    left_of([_, black, _, _, _, _], [_, _, dubstep, _, _, _], DJs),

    % Clue 7
    next_to([french, _, _, _, _, _], [_, blue, _, _, _, _], DJs),

    % Clue 8
    (DJs = [[_, _, _, _, _, camping], _, _, _, _] ; DJs = [_, _, _, _, [_, _, _, _, _, camping]]),

    % Clue 9
    member([_, blue, _, asgard, _, _], DJs),

    % Clue 10
    left_of([_, green, _, _, _, _], [_, _, _, _, _, painting], DJs),
    left_of([_, _, _, _, _, painting], [_, blue, _, _, _, _], DJs),

    % Clue 11
    DJs = [_, _, _, [_, _, _, _, 40, _], _],

    % Clue 12
    next_to([_, _, trance, _, _, _], [_, _, dubstep, _, _, _], DJs),

    % Clue 13
    left_of([canadian, _, _, _, _, _], [_, _, _, _, _, juggling], DJs),

    % Clue 14
    left_of([_, black, _, _, _, _], [_, _, _, _, _, singing], DJs),

    % Clue 15
    next_to([_, _, _, _, 35, _], [_, _, _, _, _, juggling], DJs),

    % Clue 16
    left_of([dutch, _, _, _, _, _], [_, _, _, _, 25, _], DJs),
    left_of([_, _, _, _, 25, _], [_, _, _, _, 40, _], DJs),

    % Clue 17
    left_of([_, blue, _, _, _, _], [_, _, _, xibalba, _, _], DJs),

    % Clue 18
    member([_, _, _, valhalla, _, surfing],DJs),

    % Clue 19
    member([_, red, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    left_of([french, _, _, _, _, _], [_, red, _, _, _, _], DJs),

    % Check properties
    member([american, _, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([canadian, _, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([dutch, _, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([french, _, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([scottish, _, _, _, _, _], DJs),

    member([_, black, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, blue, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, green, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, red, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, white, _, _, _, _], DJs),

    member([_, _, drum_and_bass, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, _, dubstep, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, _, edm, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, _, house, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, _, trance, _, _, _], DJs),

    member([_, _, _, arcadia, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, _, _, asgard, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, _, _, shangri_la, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, _, _, valhalla, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, _, _, xibalba, _, _], DJs),

    member([_, _, _, _, 25, _], DJs),
    member([_, _, _, _, 30, _], DJs),
    member([_, _, _, _, 35, _], DJs),
    member([_, _, _, _, 40, _], DJs),
    member([_, _, _, _, 45, _], DJs),

    member([_, _, _, _, _, camping], DJs),
    member([_, _, _, _, _, juggling], DJs),
    member([_, _, _, _, _, painting], DJs),
    member([_, _, _, _, _, singing], DJs),
    member([_, _, _, _, _, surfing], DJs).
```

Comment: Usual reminder: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Comment: Why are you defining member/2, when swi-prolog has a superior definition built-in? https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#member/2

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, what is wrong with `left_of/2`?

Comment: Here's a start: length(AllNationalities,5), length(AllColors,5), nth1(CanadianLoc,AllNationalities,canada), nth1(BlackLoc,AllColors,black),CanadianLoc < BlackLoc, %canadian is left of black
...so you start with unassigned lists of length 5; apply some rules; apply more rules. When done, be sure AllNationalities is a permutation of the list of available nationalities (use permutation/2).

Comment: @false I was mixing up its interaction with member/2; if the Scottish person is supposed to be `left_of` the person in the white shirt, then `[scott, white, _, _, _, _]` should not be one of the things it suggests but it wasn't left_of doing that.

Comment: Looking at clue 1 - the 2 `member` lines are unnecessary, because a correct `left_of` predicate would itself be ensuring membership.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your code into small manageable parts first. And then, use the [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel) to see if the answers you get are the answers you want. Just your first clue is:

```
clue1(DJs) :-
    DJs = [_, _, _, _, _],
    % Clue 1
    member([scott, _, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([_, white, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    left_of([scott, _, _, _, _, _], [_, white, _, _, _, _], DJs).

?- clue1(DJs).
   DJs = [[scott,white,_A,_B,_C,_D],[_E,white,_F,_G,_H,_I],_J,_K,_L], unexpected
;  DJs = [[scott,white,_A,_B,_C,_D],_E,[_F,white,_G,_H,_I,_J],_K,_L], unexpected
;  ... % many answers omitted
;  DJs = [[_A,white,_B,_C,_D,_E],[scott,_F,_G,_H,_I,_J],[_K,white,_L,_M,_N,_O],_P,_Q], unexpected
;  ... % many answers omitted
;  false.
```

In total, just for the first clue, there are 250 answers.  Many of which can never lead to a solution: The first two answers have two `white` instead of just one. The last shown answer has `scott` to the right (and not left) of a `white`. It is quite similar with the subsequent clues. Let's remove the two `member/2` goals since they are already implied by `left_of/2`.  As a result we narrowed down the problem to 10 answers.

```
?- clue1(DJs).
   DJs = [[scott,_A,_B,_C,_D,_E],[_F,white,_G,_H,_I,_J],_K,_L,_M]
;  DJs = [[scott,_A,_B,_C,_D,_E],_F,[_G,white,_H,_I,_J,_K],_L,_M]
;  DJs = [[scott,_A,_B,_C,_D,_E],_F,_G,[_H,white,_I,_J,_K,_L],_M]
;  DJs = [[scott,_A,_B,_C,_D,_E],_F,_G,_H,[_I,white,_J,_K,_L,_M]]
;  DJs = [_A,[scott,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F],[_G,white,_H,_I,_J,_K],_L,_M]
;  DJs = [_A,[scott,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F],_G,[_H,white,_I,_J,_K,_L],_M]
;  DJs = [_A,[scott,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F],_G,_H,[_I,white,_J,_K,_L,_M]]
;  DJs = [_A,_B,[scott,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G],[_H,white,_I,_J,_K,_L],_M]
;  DJs = [_A,_B,[scott,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G],_H,[_I,white,_J,_K,_L,_M]]
;  DJs = [_A,_B,_C,[scott,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H],[_I,white,_J,_K,_L,_M]]
;  false.
```

Now, you can observe the failure with some patience. To improve speed you could move up clues, that consist of a single unification like, clue 2, 3, and 11. Also you could ensure with the help of `dif/2` that all corresponding entries are different. This would improve speed, but still there would be failure.

Here is a **generalization** of your program that still fails. I have removed many of the goals in it, leaving only:

```
solve(DJs) :-
    DJs = [_, _, _, _, _],
    left_of([scott, _, _, _, _, _], [_, white, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([american, _, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([canadian, _, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([dutch, _, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([french, _, _, _, _, _], DJs),
    member([scottish, _, _, _, _, _], DJs).

?- solvex(DJs).
   false, unexpected.
```

*Because* this fragment fails, also your original program will fail. By fixing this problem, your program works. So you should be able to figure that out. Finally, your problem has, however, 48 solutions which is a bit unusual for a zebra puzzle which typically has only a single solution.